# How can I use Cucumber to test Devise's Rememberable functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, devise

I'd like to have a Cucumber feature testing the rememberable functionality of devise (a remember me cookie).

It is easy to check the remember me check box using capybara but how should I simulate a user returning to the site after closing their window?

Comment: Why would you want to when devise itself will do this apart of there tests ?

Comment: Because I think it is important to make sure that I am testing this feature at the integration level - that is - am I using it correctly?, is it working correctly?, and can my clients see that it is working correctly in cucumber based acceptance tests?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following rack-test hack, and slightly cleaner selenium api use, to test Devise remember-me functionality in cucumber/capybara. It just tells the driver to manually erase the session cookie. Not all drivers are supported, I only implemented the two I've used:

http://gist.github.com/484787

This assumes cookie storage of the session. Remove @announce tag from the scenario to get rid of the verbosity.

Another option, suggested by Matt Wynne in [the mailing list discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/8e83ea8432cfb3f8), may be looking at other cookie stores, and deleting them by query or file deletion:

lifted from agile rails book:

```
config.action_controller.session_store = CGI::Session::PStore (or just :p_store)
config.action_controller.session_options[:tmpdir] = "/Users/dave/tmp" 
config.action_controller.session_options[:prefix] = "myapp_session_"
```

or

```
rake db:sessions:create
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

Rails also has a reset session method, but I believe we don't have access to this because we can't hook into the rails session when testing with capybara.

Hope this helps,

Nick

Answer (score 1):

nruth's gist was really helpful but I felt like deleting the cookie by name was cheating. I created a step that deletes the cookies a browser would delete when it was closed and restarted (any cookie without an expiry date set and set in the future).

You can see it in [this commit](https://github.com/JamesFerguson/Ranker/commit/17f010a2438ac32086e329f73c80c65fd1895f4c) (though I've only done it for the RackTest driver as I don't have Selenium setup). You can also see my login/remember_me feature in [this commit](https://github.com/JamesFerguson/Ranker/commit/759fc62bae45f9e3ff7071b5bd190623738a06b7). And I refactored the classes to separate files in [this commit](https://github.com/JamesFerguson/Ranker/commit/874faaa6d168dec5846d602fb955c46fa5d29d05).

I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used [email-spec](http://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) to accomplish this.  My Scenario looks like the following:

```
@allow-rescue
Scenario: Create New Account (Everything cool)
Given I am not authenticated
When I go to register
And I fill in "Name" with "bill"
And I fill in "Email" with "bill@example.com"
And I fill in "Password" with "please"
And I fill in "Password Confirmation" with "please"
And I press "Sign up"
Then "bill@example.com" should receive an email
And I open the email
And I should see "Confirm my account" in the email body
When I follow "Confirm my account" in the email
Then I should see "Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in."
```

Note the **@allow-rescue** decoration above the scenario that is necessary when using Devise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's handy stuff, particularly email-spec, however I wanted to know about testing Devise's rememberable functionality - that is the cookie storage ability so users don't need to constantly login everytime they visit the site.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could log out with capybara, and then log back in something like

```
Given I am on the login screen
And I select 'Remember Me'
And I click 'login'
Then I should be 'logged in'
When I click 'log out'
Then I should be 'logged out' #=> potentially destroy a session here?
When I click log in
Then I should be logged in
And I should not be directed to the login form.
```

This *should* use cabybara's current cookie state to model this flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [show_me_the_cookies](https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies) for this as shown below:

```
And(/^I leave the site$/) do
  expire_cookies
end
```